# Moving and covering light fixtures in bathroom

Tags: bathroom, drywall, light-fixture, junction-box, patching-drywall

I currently have 2 small light fixtures in my bathroom on either side of my mirror above the sink.  My plan is to add a new fixture above the mirror and patch/cover the existing fixtures.  It's first floor, so I have no access above.

1) What is the best way to wire the new junction box for the new fixture above?  Should I just continue wires to the new fixture from one of the old side fixture boxes and just leave the wires on the other old side fixture box?

2) What is the best way to get the wires to the new box without ripping out a ton of drywall?  I'd imagine I'd have to drill through a stud to get to the new fixture.  Or am I going to have to cut out extra drywall just to get my drill in there and do work?

3) Once the new fixture is in, are there any special codes/considerations I should be aware of to cover the old boxes and drywall over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. How you get the wire there depends on framing, access, etc. Hard for us to say. Ideally you have a continuous cable from the switch or power source. Old wires need to be disconnected at both ends.
2. Ditto.
3. You can't cover junction boxes that are in use. You'll need to have a continuous cable from your switch, or you'll need to put a decorative plate over any remaining boxes and keep them accessible.